# How to show all recent modified items list on Home Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I need to show recent modified items of a List or library on home page something like below image. Is it possible using a Web Part. I have tried using *content search web part* but didn't get the expected results. Kindly suggest

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Highlighted Content" Web Part on your SharePoint Online modern sites.

Configure the web part properties to the list or library you want to see items from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the "Recently Changed Items" web part under the "Search Driven Content" category.

You can change the query by editing this web part to narrow down your results to specific lists/libraries.

Comment: does this answers your question?